# What is the default expiry time for Rails cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've done some googling and couldn't find the answer to this question. Rails allows to specify expiry times for its cache like that:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("my_var", :expires_in => 10.seconds)
```

But what happens if I specify nothing:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("my_var")
```

It never expires? Is there a default value? How can I explicitly define something that never expires?

Comment: setting the expiry on `fetch` doesn't have any effect unless a block is given

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It really depends on which cache storage you're using. Rails provides several, one of them most popular is [Memcached](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore). One of key features of Memcached is that it [automatically expires old unused records](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Overview#forgetting-is-a-feature), so you can forget about :expire option.

Other Rails cache storages, like memory storage or redis storage will keep will not expire date unless you explicitly specify when to do that.

[More about how cache key expiration works in Rails.](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works)

Comment: I use :expires_in as a mean to define how new I think the data needs to be. If I think that it's ok with 5 minutes old data for something, I use expires_in: 5.minutes. My main reason for caching is to speed things up for concurrency and hammering.

Comment: @OskarHolmkratz A useful alternative can be to use a cache key that reflects the version (that's why ActiveRecord has the .cache_key attribute, which is based on updated_at timestamp). Then you never have to worry about expiry, you'll be showing latest result and old data will be purged automatically.

Answer (score 10):

Using Dalli for memcached (who doesn't), the default expiry time is never, as @Rahul says. You don't have to worry about garbage collection, as @icem says, memcached throw out the old unused records.

See the official dalli documentation:

```
Expires_in default is 0, which means never
```

https://github.com/mperham/dalli#configuration

you can set the global expiry time for dalli

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { expires_in: 1.day}
```

and for better individual control:

```
Rails.cache.write "some_cache_key", some_cachable_string, expires_in: 3.hours
```

the new doc http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store/write doesn't say much, but the old does:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemCacheStore/write

manually expire a cache (if some event occurred):

```
Rails.cache.delete "some_cache_key"
```

Answer (score 6):

They never expires. (for FileStore based cache, which is default in Rails)

If they key is found in the cache store, the value would be used. Thus it is always recommended to add atleast any expiry time.

Comment: That seems logic but do you have any references for that? I've been searching a lot and I can find it nowhere. Besides, my system behaves like if there was a default expiry time and I would like to rule out the possibility of being due to some cache hidden default value. Also, wouldn't this be dependent on the underlying cache store?