# Rails caching only works when expiry is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Just wondering why you have to set a expiry for caching to work in console?
Apparently [leaving it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404584/what-is-the-default-expiry-time-for-rails-cache), it should never expire - yet I can't get it to work? If I don't set an expiry, the key isn't returned.

```
1.9.3p392 :014 > Rails.cache.write "foo", "bar"
1.9.3p392 :015 > Rails.cache.read "foo"
 => nil 
1.9.3p392 :016 > 
1.9.3p392 :017 > Rails.cache.write "foo", "bar", :expires_in => 3.hours
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :018 > 
1.9.3p392 :019 > Rails.cache.read "foo"
 => "bar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that removing the "expires_at" from the cache_store config did the trick. I don't need to set an expiry because memcache will clear out the oldest when it gets full etc (as per russian doll caching).

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1:11211', { :namespace => 'blah', :expires_in => 3.months, :compress => true }
```

becomes

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1:11211', { :namespace => 'blah', :compress => true }
```